# Vertex and Vector3 are not interchangeable in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Starting on three.js revision 48 I made vertices connected by lines. It works fine but when updating to revision 65 from 48 I get an error message saying that Vertix is deprecated and should be replaced by Vector3. However, when I replace it with Vector3, Vector2 or Vector4 it behaves differently – the lines won't connect to the vertices anymore. I also get some strange rendering problems on the edges when the canvas is the width of the viewport.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,10000);
var distance = 1000; 
camera.position.z = distance;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(camera);

renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

for ( var i = 0; i < 50; i ++ ) {

    particle = new THREE.Particle( new THREE.ParticleCanvasMaterial( {

        color: Math.random() * 0x808080 + 0x808080, //0x0000000,
        opacity: 1,//0.1,
        program: function ( context ) {

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc( 0, 0, 1, 0, Math.PI * 2, true );
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();

        }

    } ) );
    particle.position.x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
    particle.position.y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
    particle.position.z = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
    particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = Math.random() * 12 + 5;
    scene.add( particle );

    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex( particle.position ) );

}

var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, opacity: 0.05 } ) );
scene.add( line );

renderer.render( scene, camera );

document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );

function onMouseMove(event){
    mouseX = (event.clientX - window.innerWidth/2) / window.innerWidth/2;
    mouseY = (event.clientY - window.innerHeight/2) / window.innerHeight/2;
    camera.position.x = Math.sin(mouseX * Math.PI) * distance;
    camera.position.y = - Math.sin(mouseY * Math.PI) * distance;
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Try replacing the Vertex at line 42 with Vector3: http://jsfiddle.net/kz94z/

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this line:

```
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex( particle.position ) );
```

to this:

```
geometry.vertices.push( particle.position );
```

Comment: It worked because you just got an answer from the guy who created Three.JS ^_^